# Row-wise extract column names from DataFrame into Series

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to extract the column names in a list to a Series filtered on the values in each row

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd   

In [2]: df =pd.DataFrame({'colA':[1,0,1], 'colB':[0,0,1], 'colC':[1,0,0]})    

In [3]: print(df)

   colA  colB  colC
0     1     0     1
1     0     0     0
2     1     1     0
```

The resulting Series should look like this:

```
0    [colA, colC]
1              []
2    [colA, colB]
dtype: object
```

Here's the tortured solution I came up with:

```
In [4]: df2 = df.T

In [5]: l = [df2[df2[i]>0].index.values.tolist() for i in range(3)]

In [6]: print(pd.Series(l))

0    [colA, colC]
1              []
2    [colA, colB]
dtype: object
```

Is there a less tortured way of doing this?

Comment: No, I don't see a better solution than the one you have now. The string-based solutions are likely less efficient and generally more verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) assuming your dataframe is constituted by 0's and 1's, and create a Series from the result:

```
x = np.where(df,df.columns,'')
pd.Series([' '.join(i).split() for i in x])
0    [colA, colC]
1              []
2    [colA, colB]
```

Comment: I've dropped the requirement that the series contains lists and still this solution was fastest mostly due to the necessity to add a ',' in @coldspeed's answer. Here are the timings: Using boolean selection : 1.6805166320409626
Using dot : 0.7504195640794933
Using where : 0.44714107702020556